# What is the best way to utilize storage space on multiple (cloud) servers?

Tags: linux, cloud-storage

I have access to multiple cloud servers (all linux based) - the only problem is that they are somewhat limited on their storage capacity (around 50-100GB). The server just provide storage for actively access files from our customers (typical hosted data: images, documents, etc).

My goal is to have a solution that can scale and be seamlessly integrated, as well as redundant. Meaning, I can't just split up the file storage, there needs to be some kind of backup as well. So basically 1) make the storage unified and connected 2) provide some form of redundancy.

Again, these are linux based servers. In time, I can migrate to a more dedicated solution. But since I am on a budget, I want to utilize these smaller scale servers for now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [MogileFS](http://www.danga.com/mogilefs/), it looks like it would fit your requirements pretty well.

Comment: Thank you! that sounds like exactly what I was looking for